# webclient how to keep basic authorization when redirect

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cookies, redirect, webclient

I use webclient to call a web service, I pass username & password as basic authorizaiton in webclient header.  The request is redirected to another URL, but basic authorizaiton info is not included in the re-directed request header, so I get 401 not authorized error.  So how to keep authorization info in request header when redirect? thanks 
I notice the authorization is actually carried in cookies

I am using C# , .NEt 4.0, VS2010

Answer (score 1):

webclient strips out your customer authentication headers, and for good reason! If you get redirected to *who knows where?*, you certainly don't want to be sending them your authentication information!

If you are getting redirected to somewhere in the same directory (I think?) then you can use

```
Request.PreAuthenticate = true
```

but odds are that you will need to set up your program to handle the redirect manually, and then use a webclient request to connect to the correct server.

Comment: Thanks, I did set it, but still get 401 error. Yes, the same directory of the same server

Comment: webclient is probably too high level for what you are trying to do then. I would look into using HttpWebRequest

Comment: I used httpwebrequest, set PreAuthenticate = true, still not working. thanks