# Can a curl command passing in a username and password credentials in the URL work in a C# program/.net environment

Tags: c#, http, unix

Can a curl command passing in a username and password credentials in the URL work in a C# program/.net environment?

Example:
curl -T testfile.txt 'http://user:password@domain.net/dir/

What would be the equivalent of the Curl command in a C# .net environment?

My original problem started by trying to uplaod a file to a webdav server. I tried using C# webclient and httpwebrequest...... and keep getting 401 autnetication errors even though the credentials was in the actual header of the request.

When I use Curl in a unix environment I had no problems uploading the file.

I am not sure if the problem is with the redirect that HttpWebrequest does:

[webclient how to keep basic authorization when redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846408/webclient-how-to-keep-basic-authorization-when-redirect)

Thats is:

401 - authentication error - No username and password in header

Then - 301 redirect - This includes username and password in header

Answer (score 0):

just try the below code... it will help you...

```
string fileToUpload = @"c:\testfile.txt";
FileStream rdr = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open);
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Upload"); 
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("username", "password");
req.Method = "POST"; 
req.ContentLength = rdr.Length;
req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
Console.WriteLine(rdr.Length);                
byte[] inData = new byte[rdr.Length];

// Get data from upload file to inData 
int bytesRead = rdr.Read(inData, 0, (int)rdr.Length);

// put data into request stream
reqStream.Write(inData, 0, (int)rdr.Length);
rdr.Close();

req.GetResponse();
// after uploading close stream 
reqStream.Close();
```

Comment: I Pandian. Thank you. This did not work. Stell getting 401 authentication error. The program attemps to upload - no user/password in header then do a redirect - User and password inclduded . See:nhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846408/webclient-how-to-keep-basic-authorization-when-redirect

Comment: The question may be how do I prevent httpwebrequest from doing a redirect?